# Extend android app

Tags: android, components

I'd like to create an app that is the same as the default camera app only with one small modification (i.e. video disabled or extra functionality added). How do I do it?

Do I just get the source code of the camera app and modify it or is there a way to extend core components of the Android system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is open source, so you can download the source for every stock-app in android (not for the google apps like Maps). You can in fact download the most recent original camera app from [the android git repo](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=tree). The building of the apk is only possible if you download the whole android-source. For a overview how to build the android-source, see [this howto](http://source.android.com/porting/build_system.html). You could modify the source for your needs.

I'm quite sure that it is impossible to extend the camera-app without copying the source because there is no plugin-api (or similiar) for the camera-api.

Comment: Actually, you could patch the binary using apktool.  For built-ins that are not proper SDK apps and so will only compile in the context of a platform build, I've sometimes found this worthwhile.  If I can't figure out the change directly in dalvik code, I get a small chunk of source code around the change adapted to compile under the sdk (by stubbing out private functions, etc) and then use that as a guide / cut-and-paste source to modify the dalvik code.

Answer (score 2):

bizso99,

You can call an `Intent` from your `Activity` that is simply the camera sans video functionality like so:

```
public void imageFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

This will return a smaller thumbnail version of the image.  If you want the full size you need to use the `Mediastore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` like so:

```
public void imageFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    mImageFile = new File(pathToStoreImage);  //file where image will be stored
    mSelectedImagePath = mImageFile.getAbsolutePath();  //path to file where image will be stored
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mImageFile));
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

Then you can receive the picture in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: I see, is there a way I could add new functionality to the default system camera app, while keeping all existing functionality, and present it as a standalone app called 'camera plus'?

Comment: I don't believe it could be done with this method unless you planned on only doing post image processing.  Otherwise you would have to hook into the camera and display the stream on your own `Canvas` object and manually handle everything using the `Camera Class`.